# Relative path's to images and sound in Java

Tags: java

Currently the project that I am making is game made with Jframe/Jpanel. I am using imports of images and sound through:

images:

```
    ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Home/IdeaProjects/Game/src/DragonRoll/sprites/user_sprite_down.png");
    player = a.getImage();
    //sign
```

Sound:

```
    String gongFile = ("C:/Users/Home/IdeaProjects/Game/src/DragonRoll/music/game_track.wav");
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(gongFile);
    AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
    AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
```

The images and the soundtrack from the example is seen to be imported from a direct path not a relative one meaning that it does not work on other computer or devices since they do not have the exact same path. Can someone recommend any solutions to this, please provide example code. I have tried just removing the path except the folder which contains the images and the image name itself but that did not work.

I am using Intellij and running as an executable java file.
Also the folder which contains all of the project goes like:
- Main project folder
- Branches into .idea, out and src
- src contains classes of the game and 2 folders called images and music

Comment: Do you use a JAR ? Where do you want to store your resource files ? In your programm ?in a common dir  ? In a relative dir ?

Comment: I have the project file itself and inside the src file i have my classes and then inside the src also i has 2 folders one for images and the other for the sound

Comment: Yes but you have to create a executable file for executed this project outside your development environment such as a JAR.
What is your front api ?

Comment: i use intellij and i run it as an executable jar when playing the game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention source files in a Java project (everything that ends with `.java`) should be in a folder called `src/main/java`. Resources such as images, audio files, default config files, etc. are usually placed in a second source folder called `src/main/resources`. This way the compiled sources (i.e. the `.class` files) and the resource files will be on the classpath at run time of your application.

To load for example the `src/main/resources/DragonRole/music/game_track.wav` resource from your classpath you can simply do this:

```
InputStream gameTrackIn = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(
     "/DragonRole/music/game_track.wav");
```

To load the `src/main/resources/DragonRoll/sprites/user_sprite_down.png` resource from your classpath you can simply do this:

```
ImageIcon userSpriteDownImg = new ImageIcon(MyClass.class.getResource(
     "/DragonRoll/sprites/user_sprite_down.png"));
```

Your project structure should look like this:

```
Game (project root)
  └ src/main
     ├ java (source root)
     └ resources (resource root)
```

Comment: so i move all my classes that are in DragonRoll to a folder called main in src ? Am I understanding correctly, also if so do i move the classes out of the folder DragonRoll and put them into the main or instead the whole folder called DragonRoll.

Comment: Yes that looks good. However you need to make sure to mark the `java` folder as "Source Root" and the `resources` folder as "Resource Root" in IntelliJ and not the `src` folder.

Comment: how do you mark something ? when i tried right clicking and going to mark it only have the options of marking as Excluded.

Comment: are you still there?

Comment: You probably need to unmark the `src` folder first, as you can't add another source or resource folder under an existing source folder.

Comment: ok, done. can you provide an example of an image import from what i have right now ?

Answer (score 0):

Basing on your comment responses, I propose you to place your resource files inside the jar.
After, Accessing to a resource file can be done in a such way :   `YourClass.class.getResource("sun.png")` **if the file is at the correct place.**

Your main task now is placing the resource files to the convenient place and ensuring that you build allows to create the JAR with the expected files in the expected directory.
You don't seem to use Maven. It is not a prerequisite but it could easy your work to create the jar.
It's a common question. You should find some good examples about it.

Comment: Yes but i don't see your pom.xml. If you don't know Maven, take a time to understand its working.

Comment: what's the purpose of a pom ? and how would i create one

Comment: If you don't know Maven, take a time to understand its working. Otherwise, you will encounter difficulties.
Pom is the file which describes the build of your component (for you your jar). With Intelij, you can create Maven project with Wizard. Try it and document you about it :)

Comment: is there a temporary solution that i could use right now since i want it to be working so then i can explore more permanent solutions ?

Comment: yes but it risks to be complicated and consuming time if you don't use a build tool explicitly (maven, ant, gradle, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using:

```
ImageIcon c = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/sprites/new_background_panel.png");
```

Meaning it was looking from the source folder and not the whole computers path, thanks all others who helped out.